# How can i improve this code maximum distance to the closest person

Tags: python, arrays

**Problem statement**
You are given an array representing a row of seats where `seats[i] = 1` represents a person sitting in the ith seat, and `seats[i] = 0` represents that the ith seat is empty (0-indexed).
There is at least one empty seat, and at least one person sitting.
Alex wants to sit in the seat such that the distance between him and the closest person to him is maximized. 
Return that maximum distance to the closest person.
[Link to the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximize-distance-to-closest-person)

**Code**

```
import math
class Solution(object):
    def maxDistToClosest(self, seats):
        left_max = 0
        right_max = 0
        if seats[0] == 0:
            i=0
            while seats[i] == 0:
                left_max+=1
                i+=1

        if seats[len(seats)-1] == 0:
            j=len(seats)-1
            while seats[j] == 0:
                right_max+=1
                j-=1
        curr_count=0
        max_count=0
        for i, value in enumerate(seats):
            if value ==0:
                curr_count+=1
            if value == 1 and curr_count !=0:
                max_count = max(curr_count, max_count)
                curr_count = 0

        a = max(left_max, right_max)
        b = (max_count+1)/2
        #print(right_max)
        #print(b, max_count, right_max)
        return max(int(b), a)

solution = Solution()
arr = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1]
a = solution.maxDistToClosest(arr)
print("Output:", a) #expected output 2

arr = [1,0,0,0]
a = solution.maxDistToClosest(arr)
print("Output:", a) #expected output 3

arr = [0,1]
a = solution.maxDistToClosest(arr)
print("Output:", a) #expected output 1

arr = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
a = solution.maxDistToClosest(arr)
print("Output:", a) #expecte output 2
```

This code works, but a very naive way to solve the problem. Is it possible to improve this? with readibility, or removing extra loops or logic?

Answer (score 0):

This can be greatly simplified as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def maxDistToClosest(self, seats: List[int]) -> int:
        c = p = seats.index(1)

        for i, s in enumerate(seats[p+1:], p+1):
            if s:
                c = max(c, (i - p) // 2)
                p = i

        return c if seats[-1] else max(c, len(seats) - p - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want something like this:

```py
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def maxDistToClosest(self, seats: List[int]) -> int:
        distances: set[int] = set()
        length = len(seats)
        start_index = 1
        if seats[0] == 0:
            d = 1
            for i in range(start_index, length):
                if seats[i] == 0:
                    d += 1
                else:
                    break
            else:
                return d  # 只有最后一个位有人的情况
            start_index = i + 1
            distances.add(d)
        d = 0
        for i in range(start_index, length):
            if seats[i] == 0:
                d += 1
            else:
                distances.add((d + 1) // 2)
                d = 0
        if d != 0:
            distances.add(d)  # 最后一个位为空的情况
        return max(distances)


def main():
    s = Solution()
    seats = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    expect = 2
    result = s.maxDistToClosest(seats)
    assert result == expect, f"{seats=}. Expected: {expect}, Got: {result}"
    seats = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    expect = 3
    result = s.maxDistToClosest(seats)
    assert result == expect, f"{seats=}. Expected: {expect}, Got: {result}"
    seats = [0, 1]
    expect = 1
    result = s.maxDistToClosest(seats)
    assert result == expect, f"{seats=}. Expected: {expect}, Got: {result}"
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```